# Difference between implicit and explicit io namespace functions in Lua

Tags: lua

What is exact difference between implicit functions and explicit function in lua ? I came across these terms while reading about file operations in Lua.Implicit functions are preceded by `io.`like `io.read()`whereas explicit functions look something like `file:read()`.I am clueless about the difference though the book says

> The difference between the two is that implicit functions work on the
>   default file as provided by the `io` namespace, whereas explicit
>   functions work with a file handle provided from a previous
>   operation,such as `io.open`

Any better explanation, please ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`io.read` reads from the default input file.

The default input file is `stdin`, but you change it by calling `io.input`.

You can also open a file explicitly with `io.open` and the use the returned handle in method calls, such as `f:read()`.

`io.read()` is equivalent to `io.input():read()`.

See also http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#6.8.

Comment: Note that this is a convention that only applies to the `io` functions, and not to Lua functions in general.